# Could someone explain to me why a webpage loads faster when you load CSS files before script files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWF7ZzPyagE), and found some elements of it going over my head.

He says that scripts are 'serialized' and also block subsequent files from being loaded. If this is the case then `Script 1` would finish loading and then `Script 2` would begin loading and then the CSS files would load.

I do not see how loading the CSS files before would inhibit this behaviour. Since the script files should have a set waiting time even if they are loaded one after the other, swapping around the order should not change this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should put scripts just before closing the body tag, that way all content and style is loaded before js kicks in.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. Some of the JS may be dependent on the DOM elements being present and can see you having synchronicity issues if you don't. However the speed remains unexplained.

Comment: that advice as written here is wrong or at least outmoded; scipts all load at the same time these days, mitigating what used to be rather large performance impacts based upon placement.

Comment: @dandavis are you sure? Are scripts now loaded in parallel but executed in the proper order??

Comment: @m59: exactly, they ARE executed in order, but script parging./executing is much faster than fetching over a wire, so the delay is nowhere near what it used to be, and piplining lets many script come in, even while other script executes and fetches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocking the CSS file won't block the page load, but it will cause the page to be re-rendered; possibly causing a noticeable flicker. This is because each time the browser encounters another block of CSS it needs to re-render the DOM, in case the new styles change anything.

This is all about user experience / perceptual load speed:

- Put CSS as high as possible (pref in `<head>`) to negate the chance of the DOM being re-rendered
- Keep JS scripts as low as possible (pref just before `</body>`) because it ensures the DOM is loaded into the browser (and therefore visible to the user) before any potentially blocking external scripts are loaded

Comment: along that line, <link>'s can be fetched as soon as the HTML hits the browser, but import can't fetch until the sheet arrives. so, even though it doesn't look as nice as import, many <link> tags will perform better both physically and perceptually.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers are now better about allowing things to "load" in parallel, but scripts will be executed in the order they appear on the page. The video's advice applies best to older browsers. The best thing you can do is move script tags to just before the closing of the body tag so that the page will be rendered before needing to execute all of your javascript. Here is the Google Best Practices recommendation about this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_javascript_last

Also note that it is potentially a great performance benefit if you load scripts from a CDN.  For example, if you include your own copy of jQuery, every person that visits your site the first time must download it. If you link to jQuery from its CDN, your users have likely already downloaded that same file while visiting another site, and that same file will be used when they visit your site, thus no reason to download it again from you. Also, if you're loading a lot of scripts at once from your server, the download of some of them could be delayed, so loading from other sources opens that up as well.

**Regarding the video (outdated):**

He's saying that the css files will begin downloading if they come before the script tags. If your script tags are already loading, the css files won't begin loading until the scripts are done.

To exaggerate the issue, imagine that if one `script` begins to load, we won't allow anything else to start loading at all. On the other hand, if a `css file` starts to load, the next `script` can begin to load immediately after the `css file` starts to load. This way, they are both loading at the same time. However, if a `script` begins to load, the `css file` CANNOT begin to load until the script is fully loaded.

Comment: what browser still pauses upon loading a script tag?

Comment: @dandavis so, would I be correct in saying that the video's information is now outdated and irrelevant?

Comment: irrelevant sounds harsh and overly pejorative. The old rules still apply for old browsers, and the old strategy plays well today. And, a single really slow script can stall the page still. i would have mentioned defer and async attributes as a way to circumvent potential slow-loading script problems... though outdated, the advice is still not bad.

Comment: @dandavis well, I updated the answer with that and all the info I have on script loading. It would be really appreciated if you could double check me. You're welcome to edit any stupid thing I said, or just let me know. I code a LOT but I'm still fairly new :)

Answer (score 0):

Its generally good practice to load your JS files at the bottom of your page as you then give HTTP request priority to other elements on the page such as styles (CSS), images and text etc. These will be shown visually to the user first instead of waiting for scripts to load in the background.

Comment: no browser since IE7 has only fetched 2 urls at once. These days you get at least 4-8 per server, 8-16 overall...